# Flask and Celery translations in render_template out of app context error

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a Flask application from which I want to send emails, which have a translatable string in the template, using `Flask-Babel`.

```
@celery.task
def send_email(user_email=None):
    with app.app_context():
         html = render_template('user/email_template.html')
         subject = lazy_gettext(u'Subject Line')
         send_email(user_email, subject, html)


 @app.route('/index/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 @login_required
 def index():
    ...
    send_email.delay(
         user_email=user.email,
    )
```

*email_template.html*

```
<p>{{ _('Email Test') }}</p>
```

This results in the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ugettext'
```

This does not happen when I call the `send_email` function without Celery.  Do I somehow have to pass the app context to Celery?

*N.B. Abbreviated for clarity*

**EDIT**

*Full stacktrace:*

```
[2016-03-28 12:08:30,528: ERROR/MainProcess] Task main.send_unlock_email[98f520d4-fadf-4272-8c14-17d6c16bf182] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ugettext'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>flask-projects/<env>/<env>/views/main.py", line 84, in send_unlock_email
    html = render_template('user/successfull_unlock.html')
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<path>flask-projects/<env>/<env>/templates/user/successfull_unlock.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    <p>{{ _('Email Test') }}</p>
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/ext.py", line 132, in _gettext_alias
    return __context.call(__context.resolve('gettext'), *args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/ext.py", line 138, in gettext
    rv = __context.call(func, __string)
  File "<path>.envs/<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_babel/__init__.py", line 116, in <lambda>
    lambda x: get_translations().ugettext(x),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ugettext'
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: The error originates from the html template.

Comment: Added full stacktrace at bottom.